# How to Hide and show child form in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, user-interface, visual-studio-2013

I prepared  the form with using "SplitContainer tool".I added Treeview  into left side of that SplitContainer. next i added to that treeview two Node such as hide and show and also i prepared a "child form". I need to do, Chile form SplitContainer load to  right side when I click on the Node show and hide child form when click on the hide node.i can show chile form but can not hide it.please help me to do this.below i attached code which i used to "Show"

```
 private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControll.UscCreateUser UscPerobjForm = new UserControll.UscCreateUser();
        string Tree = (string)e.Node.Tag;
        if (Tree == "1")
        {
            UscPerobjForm.TopLevel = false;
            splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(UscPerobjForm);
            UscPerobjForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            UscPerobjForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            UscPerobjForm.Show();
            //Show part
        }
        else if (Tree == "2")
        {
            // Hide part
        }
    }
```

I need to **Hide part.**

Comment: You need to get an instance of a "child form" and call `Hide()` method.

Comment: while (splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Count > 0) splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls[0].Dispose();

Comment: Oh i am currently using that UscPerobjForm.Hide(); . but it's not working Mr.Alex.

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://dockpanelsuite.com/ where you can have the tree view implement in a Form class docked on Left while the Child Form dock the center.